# Passing addresses of variables into other functions

Tags: c++

Okay, if I declare/initialize a variable, and then pass it's address to another function, is that the same as saying `int* n = &i`? In other words, is the act of passing the address to another function itself CREATING a pointer? I almost wanna say to myself "yes, duh, that's a stupid question" but I just want to make sure that I am understanding this correctly.

```
foo(int* n) {
    //do something
}


main () {
  int i = 5;
  foo(&i);
}
```

Comment: That is totally correct.

Comment: `&i` creates a pointer. From the C++ Standard, [expr.unary.op]/3 "The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand."

Comment: Argument passing in most if the major languages works just like an assignment.

Comment: @Elazar *pedantic*: In C++, it works like initialization, not like assignment ;)

Comment: i think OP is asking more about the creation of a local variable in the function.

Comment: In the same paragraph, the C++ Standard says in a note: "In particular, the address of an object of type “ *cv* `T`” is “pointer to *cv* `T`”" I'd say an *address* is a value and *pointer* is (part of) a type ("part" like in *pointer to `int`*).

Comment: @DyP you are right of course.

Comment: then it's a *locally scoped* copy of either an address or part of a type, either way.

Comment: @AndyzSmith something feels (perhaps only feels) wrong about this sentence - "locally scoped" refers to the variable name while "copy" refers to the object this variable is holding... or maybe I'm overthinking this.

Comment: so, the function call puts an address ( a value ) on the stack for a jump to the subroutine and the subroutine pulls off a pointer ( to an int type ) off the stack.  the question is whether a pointer variable is created.  i'm still not sure.  ack!

Comment: @Elazar exactly why this is kinda confusing

Comment: @AndyzSmith C++ has no notion of "stack", "jump" and "subroutines". These are implementation details which are not part of the standardized language. In practice, this function will most likely be inlined and none of those are going to happen. A pointer is created because "pointer" is the type of "address". An object of type pointer is created as well (under the as-if rule), because the parameter `int*` requires it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct in your assumption, the variable int *n itself has a unique address which you can get with &n

Comment: yes, defining a parameter in a function definition is creating a variable local to the function that you work with.  In this case the variable actualy holds addresses, so it may seem confusing, but imagine what is the difference if you do *n=0* which sets **your variable off into nothingness** versus __*n=0__ which sets the value of the external variable to the number zero.